# How to assign firewall tags to a container in cloud run?

Tags: containers, firewall, google-cloud-run, vpc

I created a firewall rule (tag:mongo-db) but now I want to assign this tag to a specific container in google cloud run.

I was able to do something similar using the option to apply to all the network. But I have another container who doesn't have MongoDB.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to assign firewall tags to a container in cloud run?

A firewall tag cannot be assigned to a Cloud Run Container.

VPC Firewall rules apply to network interfaces. Cloud Run does not provide a network interface for you to manage or assign firewall rules to.

Google Cloud Run Authorization is based upon Identity-Based Authorization. Once authorization is enabled, an OIDC Identity Token is included in the HTTP **Authorization: Bearer** header to grant access.

**Advanced Features:**

Cloud Run can be assigned to an HTTP(S) Load Balancer as a backend (Serverless NEG). This allows Cloud Armor firewall rules to be deployed.

Cloud Run can also be configured to only allow traffic from a VPC (Serverless VPC Access Connector). You can restrict access to VPC resources with Firewall rules. Consult the following link:

[Restrict access to VPC resources](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc#restrict-access)